# Multilingual Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Is it possible to have multilingual jekyll website without having to maintain separate _post files?

I know that it is possible to achieve it with `_posts/2014-02-27-post.md` and `_posts/pt/2014-02-27-post.md`.

What if I can have only one post file, which defines different contents on YAML frontmatter? As far as I see, I should have multiple permalinks to the same post file. Or, to have blank `_posts/pt/2014-02-27-post.md` which merges with its parent..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately Jekyll requires one file per post, and strictly reads the file name (`yyyy-mm-dd-post-name`) in order to extract the date and the post id. 
You won't be able to maintain two posts in one file without strongly affect Jekyll engine or using javascript (you shouldn't).

*But* you can quite freely organize your `_posts` and files: you can read [Multilingual website with Jekyll](http://sylvaindurand.org/making-jekyll-multilingual/) I wrote several weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `SelectVariable` in `_config.yml` globally or locally in `YAML Header`. Now use this variable value as in select-case statement to chose content to be pasted into post out of multiple choices. Each content choice can be inserted using [contentblocks](https://github.com/rustygeldmacher/jekyll-contentblocks) plugin.

This will assist in achieving same post code but generating multiple output on different servers with flick of configuration. So lets say when `SelectVariable == 1`, contentblock #1 will be used. Easy, partial but effective.

Answer (score -2):

Like @Sylvain said, you won't be able to maintain multilingual single-file posts, but on the multiple post front, you can also use this plugin to make things easier: https://github.com/screeninteraction/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin